# CakePHP changes Blowfish passwords when getting user to verify email?

Tags: cakephp, passwords, blowfish

I have followed the CakePHP book on hashing passwords using Blowfish encryption, this works, without any problems.

I have now followed this guide, http://www.nikatrex.com/blog/?p=300 , in order to see how to verify my users email account. This works, the email I build with a link to a path to my site that then takes the email within the URL string gets the token saved within my database and if right it sets my `active` and `verify` database fields to true!

However, it also seems to change my saved Blowfish password, each time I test the link, CakePHP seems to write a new Blowfish hash into the users passwords field.

I know that the salt for Blowfish is generated at run time, so even if the password entered by the user is the same, it will save a different hashed password. That is not my problem, when I verify my users email, it re-saved the password even know I am **not** telling it to so.

So this is my users model to Blowfish the password,

```
  public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
      if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = Security::hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password'],'blowfish');
      }
      return true;
  } //End of BeforeSave
```

I have built (this is a temp, quick method for now to send email, because for some reason CakePHP email was not working for me, but I think this is down to my LAMP stack config /gmail settings) a simple mail to PHP code, this is the line that sends the link to my user,

```
  $message .= '<a href="verifymyuser/t:'.$hash.'/n:'.$this->data['User']['email'].'">CLICK HERE</a>';
```

This is my function that loads when the user clicks the link,

```
public function VerifyMe() {    
    if (!empty($this->passedArgs['n']) && !empty($this->passedArgs['t'])){
        $SentEmail = $this->passedArgs['n'];
        $SentToken = $this->passedArgs['t'];

        $GetUserToVerify = $this->User->findByEmail($SentEmail);

        if ($GetUserToVerify['User']['active'] == 0){
            if($GetUserToVerify['User']['token'] == $SentToken) {
                $GetUserToVerify['User']['active'] = true;
                $GetUserToVerify['User']['token'] = NULL;
                $GetUserToVerify['User']['verified'] = true;
                $this->User->save($GetUserToVerify);
                $this->Session->setFlash('Thank You, your email has been verified successfully, enjoy', 'GoodFlashMsg', array(), 'Good');
                $this->redirect('/login');  
                exit();         
            } 
        }  else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('You are already verified', 'BadFlashMsg', array(), 'Bad');
            $this->redirect('/');   
        } 
    } 
}
```

I am setting an 'active; 'verified' tag into the database, if later I wanted to de-active the user I can. I am also wiping the 'token' to null so that if the user changes their email address then I can set a new token, I just want to make sure it will be a new token!

I am sure its done to my model, but I can not see what is wrong with it, its got an if check for isset for the password field, which its not? Unless I am not understanding something about the way data is moving?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what is happening is hard to find with this information.
Try this, hope this will temporally solve your problem....

```
$this->User->save($GetUserToVerify, array(
    'fieldList' = array('token','active','verified')));
```

Comment: Yes that fix it, thanks - I was just looking at this, I run a debug on `$GetUserToVerify` and was shocked to find that it contained all the information from the user table. So I take it the password field was sort of set, so it was re-hashing a hashed password. - NOTE : syntax error, I had to remove the second `,` after the `$GetUserToVerify`